# Flutter align Column of text with single text

Tags: flutter, vertical-alignment

I would like to make this in Flutter:

[image: Desired result]

My code:

```
Row(
             children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: const [
                Text('Total', style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xFF68B762)),),
                Text('Km', style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xFF68B762)),),
              ],),
              const Text('612', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontFamily: SecondaryFontMedium, color: Color(0xFF68B762)),),
            ],),
```

Result:

[image: Actual result]

Comment: What's exactly wrong with it now?

Comment: what is the issue? i mean did you getting any issue to active this?

Comment: I have update it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `\n` between "Total" and "Km". Use like this way,

```
 Row(
      children: [
        Text('Total\nKm', textAlign: TextAlign.end, style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF68B762))),
        Text('612',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontFamily: SecondaryFontMedium,
                color: Color(0xFF68B762))),
      ],
    )
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: They are not aligned

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `Total` and `Km` closer together you could try setting a height in the style. For example

```
Text('Total', style: TextStyle(height: 1, color: Color(0xFF68B762))),
Text('Km', style: TextStyle(height: 1, color: Color(0xFF68B762)),),
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Nice thanx! This is what I want

Comment: @MarsMan then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Total\nKm',
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF68B762)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            '612',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                // fontFamily: SecondaryFontMedium,
                color: Color(0xFF68B762)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: They are not aligned

Comment: check my updated code now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the error is the spacing, or that the letters on the left are not aligned, but I got something like this :

```
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 40, // change this
                color: Colors.white,
                child: FittedBox( // this is important
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        'Total',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF68B762)),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Km',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF68B762)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 40, // change this
                color: Colors.white,
                child: const FittedBox( // this is important
                  child: Text(
                    '612',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1, // this is important
                      fontSize: 45,
                      color: Color(0xFF68B762),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

[image]

What I did was to add both **Container** with some equal size (40 for example), then using the Widget **FittedBox** makes that when you lower the height of the container, the letter adapts and you don't have problems...

Now in the second letter to remove the "padding" is added the **height : 1** in the **TextStyle**, if you can read more of it would be good so you don't have problems but basically it makes it possible to align with the left letters.

Try to edit the height Container and you'll see

Answer (score 0):

**changing the font size and make the row align center gives your desired result in any font**

[image: see result]

```
Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Total',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF68B762),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Km',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(
                      0xFF68B762,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              '612',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40,
                color: Color(0xFF68B762),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```